# pom profiles for jira plugin development

Tags: maven, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm building a JIRA server plugin using the latest atlassian sdk.

So for the time being I created several profiles to suport jira 6 & 7.

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${packageName}</finalName>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target-${packageName}</directory>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jira7.2.0</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>               
                <buildTestPlugin>false</buildTestPlugin>
                <applications>
                    <application>
                        <applicationKey>jira-software</applicationKey>
                        <version>${jira.software.application.version}</version>
                    </application>
                </applications>
                <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                <jvmArgs>-Xms1g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -server</jvmArgs>
                <testGroups>
                    <testGroup>
                        <id>qunit-integration</id>
                        <productIds>
                            <productId>jira</productId>
                        </productIds>
                        <includes>
                            <include>it/**/qunit/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </testGroup>
                </testGroups>

                <pluginArtifacts>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.qunit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>atlassian-qunit-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${atlassian.qunit.version}</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </pluginArtifacts>

                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                <instructions>
                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>
                        ...
                    </Export-Package>

                    <Import-Package>
                        ...                                                                                                    
                    </Import-Package>
                    <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered - see https://extranet.atlassian.com/x/xBS9hQ -->
                    <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
        </build>


            <properties> 
                <packageName>jira7.1.2</packageName>                   
                <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <jira.software.application.version>7.1.2</jira.software.application.version>
                <jira.version>7.1.2</jira.version>
                <amps.version>6.2.3</amps.version>                                 
                <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.9</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>                                 
            </properties>        
    </profile>



    <profile>
        <id>jira6.4.8</id>                 
        <build>
            .......

    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But that's only 2 jira versions and there's like one every month.

I've been wondering what is the best practice to approach pom.xml vs JIRA versions.

- How do I test my plugin against multiple jira versions
- How do I maintain the code for different jira version using GIT - I use gitflow